# Horizontal scrolling of divs inside a table PHP

Tags: php, css

how to make a horizontal scrolling with a lot of divs inside this table? I'm trying to do a     bar of friends...

```
echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td style="">';
foreach($friends as $fr){
$friend = $ots->createObject('Account');
$friend->load($fr);
$profile_img = $friend->getCustomField("profile_img");
foreach (array("/", "\\", "..") as $chan) { $profile_img = str_replace($chan, "", $profile_img); }
if (empty($profile_img) || !file_exists("account/profiles/".$profile_img)) { $profile_img = "default.png"; }
echo '<div style="border-right:1px solid #faf0d7;width:82px;height:82px;position:relative;float:left;background-image:url(account/profiles/'.$profile_img.');background-repeat:repeat-y;background-size:82px 82px;">'.$fr.'</div>';
}
echo '</td></tr></table>';
```

Note that the divs can just be at a horizontal line.
I've been tried everything I could and found at internet. Please help :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you a scrollable table cell that contains your `divs`. In your instance I would not float left your `divs`, I would instead use `display: inline-block;`

```
tr > td {
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```